# $q=1+k256$ and q is a prime,does $q|2^{k}+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$q=1+k256$ and q is a prime,$2^{k}+1>>q$, does $q|2^{k}+1$ I am stuck.

From fermat's little theorem

$2^{q-1}=2^{256k}\equiv 1 mod (q)$

assuming $x=2^{k} $, the solution to $x^{256}\equiv 1 mod(q)$ can be 1,-1 or another root, so $2^k+1 mod q$ can be 0,2 or another root+1.

This is how far I got, am I missing something or can we go further and prove that $q|2^{k}+1$ is possible or not?
Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of examples when we don't get divisibility. It is harder to find examples when both conditions 1) $q$ is a prime, and 2) $q\mid 2^k+1$, are met. Mathematica lists
$k=1092,1156,1198,1936$ as the only cases with $k\le 2000$. The corresponding values for the prime $q$ are $279553$, $295937$, $306689$ and $495617$. In that range $q$ is a prime for 328 choices of $k$.

---

Mathematica snippet:

> In[1]:= Remainders = 
>     Table[If[PrimeQ[1 + 256*k], Mod[2^k + 1, 1 + 256*k]], {k, 1, 4000}];
>
> In[2]:=Position[Remainders, 0]
>
> Out[2]:={{1092}, {1156}, {1198}, {1936}, {3145}}

So 5 examples found with $1\le k\le 4000$.

Comment: Just added the condition $2^{k}+1>>q$ to the question

Comment: Heuristically there is no case where $q|2{^k}+1$,we want either to prove that $q|2{^k}+1$ is not possible, or stating the conditions where $q|2{^k}+1$ is  possible.

Comment: I don't see anything useful. We want the order of $2$ modulo $q$ to be a factor of $2k$ but not a factor of $k$. This does not help me much.

Comment: Thanks for the mathematica work, can you send me the mathematica code? the case for k=1092 is curious as it is 1093-1,a wieferich prime -1, I wonder if this happens if k=3510, the other wieferich prime-1.

Comment: I was wondering about that Wieferichish thing myself, so I extended the search up to $k\le 4000$. Nope.